# Conditional replace for pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas `DataFrame`:

```
ID  COL1  COL2
123 1     ABC
123 1     CCC
123 NaN   AVV
345 2     FGG
345 NaN   FRG
345 NaN   FGT
```

I need to substitute all NaN values in `Col1` based on the same `ID` in order to get this result:

```
ID  COL1  COL2
123 1     ABC
123 1     CCC
123 1     AVV
345 2     FGG
345 2     FRG
345 2     FGT
```

I can write `for` loop, but it will take a long time for my dataset to execute the script. Is there any conditional replace function?

Comment: Does `df.groupby('ID').ffill().bfill()` give what you need?

Comment: @Psidom: Yes, it does. Thank you. The only problem is that it takes a long time to finish the calculation for 1GB of data

Comment: Try `df.sort_values(['ID', 'COL1']).ffill()`, which seems to be 3 ~ 4 times faster than the above method. It sorts the NaN values to the end of the data frame and use only `ffill()` method to fill missing values.

Comment: @Psidom: Could you please publish your last solution? It worked fine for me. Also I appreciate if you explain how to extend this solution to substituting any value, not only NaN. Let's say that instead of `NaN` I have `Not-Defined`. Can I still use `ffill()`?

Comment: What do you mean with `Not-Defined`? Is it a string or `null`?

Comment: @Psidom: I mean what if instead of `NaN` I have some string value that I want to substitute? What if such string value is equal to the text `Not-defined` or `Unspecified` or `ND` or whatever? Should I maybe previosly substitute all such string values with `NaN`?

Comment: Seems like an empty string. If it is, replace it with `NaN` firstly `.replace('', np.nan)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with an example as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': list(range(10)), 'COL1': [np.random.choice([1,np.nan]) for _ in range(10)]})
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop = True)

df.head()

#  COL1 ID
#0  NaN  0
#1  1.0  1
#2  1.0  2
#3  NaN  3
#4  1.0  4
```

You can use the forward fill and backward fill methods within each group to fill missing values:

```
%timeit df.groupby('ID').ffill().bfill()
1 loop, best of 3: 212 ms per loop
```

Or an alternative is to sort values by `ID` and `COL1`, this sorts `ID` firstly and then sort `COL1` within each `ID` which pushes all missing values to the end of each `ID` and then you can use `ffill()` which seems to be faster than the `ffill()`, `bfill()` methods above for this example:

```
%timeit df.sort_values(['ID', 'COL1']).ffill()
10 loops, best of 3: 71.6 ms per loop
```

---

If there are other unwanted strings, you can call the replace method to replace the strings with `NaN` firstly. For instance, if there are empty strings in the data frame you want to fill. You can do `df.replace('', np.nan).sort_values(['ID', 'COL1']).ffill()`

Answer (score 1):

How about using `Series.isnull()` to select the rows and `Series.map()` to do the conditional replacement?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [123, 123, 123, 345, 345, 345],
    'COL1': [1, 1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
    'COL2':['ABC', 'CCC', 'AVV', 'FGG', 'FRG', 'FGT']},
    columns=['ID','COL1', 'COL2'])

print df
mapping = {123: 1, 345: 2}
df.loc[df['COL1'].isnull(), 'COL1'] = df['ID'].map(mapping)
print df
```

before:

```
    ID  COL1 COL2
0  123   1.0  ABC
1  123   1.0  CCC
2  123   NaN  AVV
3  345   2.0  FGG
4  345   NaN  FRG
5  345   NaN  FGT
```

after:

```
    ID  COL1 COL2
0  123   1.0  ABC
1  123   1.0  CCC
2  123   1.0  AVV
3  345   2.0  FGG
4  345   2.0  FRG
5  345   2.0  FGT
```

EDIT: To build `mapping` programmatically, you can use these two lines of code:

```
df_unique = df.loc[df['COL1'].notnull()].groupby('ID').nth(0)
mapping = pd.Series(df_unique['COL1'].values, index=df_unique.index).to_dict()
```

Comment: Your solution is quite interesting and seems to be flexible, if you explain how to automatically create `mapping`. Thanks.

Comment: I added an edit with the automatic creation of `mapping`.  I assume my code is slower than Psidom's solution, but hopefully it's still useful to somebody.